# How to change Shopify Title if the Browser tab is active or not

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I'm trying to accomplish this in Shopify.

If the user has the browser tab active (change the page title to message A) and if the tab is not active (change page title to show message B).

For some reason, something is missing or wrong in my code.

I'm inserting this code in the header of the file: theme.liquid

```
<script>
      $(function () {
          leftTitle = 'Message A'; 
          backTitle = 'Message B';

          $(window).blur(function () {
              page.title = leftTitle;
          });

          $(window).focus(function () {
              page.title = backTitle;
          });
      });

    </script>
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

```
<script>
  var message = "Insert your message here";
  var original = document.title;

  window.onblur = function () { document.title = message; }
  window.onfocus = function () { document.title = original; }
</script>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity; how is this different from my solution?

Comment: Not too much difference. I appreciate a lot your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you're trying to use `document.title = leftTitle;` and `document.title = backTitle;`

`page` doesn't exist natively on browsers, unless you've declared it before, so `page.title` doesn't change anything; it should give you a console error.

```js
var leftTitle = 'Blurred'; 
var backTitle = 'Focused';

window.onblur = function () {
    console.log("Blur");
    document.title = leftTitle;
};

window.onfocus = function () {
    console.log("Focus");
    document.title = backTitle;
};

console.log("Event listeners initialized.");
```

Comment: it's not working. It seem Shopify is not reading that code. Maybe we need to use liquid to get this done instead of JavaScript. I don't know... I'm opening to suggestions...

Comment: Ah, that might be a different issue. Are you sure the script you wrote is successfully being included in the page you're viewing?

Comment: Is the code you're writing being included within an iframe? If so, it might be trying to change the title of the iframe document and not the parent document (as in the code snippet above).

Comment: there is nothing related to iframes. Is just a code in the header of the file theme.liquid trying to change the title when the page is active or not.

Comment: Marquizzo your code works perfectly in any other platform but doesn't work in Shopify my friend.

Comment: +1 because you provided the correct solution but OP decided to copy his solution and accept his even though it's the exact same thing!